# Trying to make columns same height with different width columns

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to make the right hand column the same height as the left hand side, the two columns are of different widths, split 25%, 75% with a form in the right hand column. I have tried several solutions, but cannot get the right hand column height to alter. Can anyone offer a solution please. The code I have written is below.

```
    <?php
include "config.php"; //Connect to Database

?>
<!doctype html>


<html>

   <head>
      <title>Login Page</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style> 
   * {
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

body {
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    }


/* Header/Blog Title */
/* Header/Blog Title */
.header img {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #f1f1f1;    

} 

.header h1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 18px;
    left: 40px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    background: #f1f1f1;    
}

/* Style the top navigation bar */
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

/* Style the topnav links */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;

}

/* Change color on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Create two unequal columns that floats next to each other */
/* Left column */

 .leftcolumn {   
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

/* Right column */

.rightcolumn {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#wrap{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
   }

.input {
    font-size: 15px;

}
form {border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;}
    input[type=text] {
     width: 100%;
     padding: 10px 20px;
     margin: 8px 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 14px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
}
button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}

button:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.cancelbtn {
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    background-color: #f44336;
}

span.psw {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 16px;
}

/* M33 image */
.m33image {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;

}
.jublogo {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;

}
.responsive {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: auto;
}

/* Add a card effect for articles */
.card {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
}
/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
 .topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}
/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 800px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

    .leftcolumn, .rightcolumn {   
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;

    }

}


/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 400px wide, make the navigation links stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    span.name {
       display: block;
       float: none;
    }
    .cancelbtn {
       width: 100%;
    }
}
      </style>

   </head>

   <body>
      <div class="#wrap">

<div class="header">
    <img src="images/BSA_logo.png" alt="BSAOC">
      <h1>Despatch Data Search Facility</h1>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>


<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Info</a>
  <a href="login.html">Login</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>


<div class="row">


  <div class="leftcolumn">
     <div class="card">
        <h2>Celebrating 60 Years</h2>
        <div class="jublogo">
          <img src="images/60_anniversay.jpg" alt="60th" class=".responsive" width="100%"height="100%"></div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p> Some text</p>
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="rightcolumn">
   <div class="card">
        <div align = "center">
         <div style = "width:250px; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; margin-top: 30px; border: solid 1px #333333; " align = "left">
            <div style = "background-color:#333333; color:#FFFFFF; padding:3px;"><b>Login</b></div>


               <form action = "login.php" method = "post">

                <div class="input">
                  <label>UserName  :</label><input type = "text" name = "name" /><br />
                  <label>Password  :</label><input type = "password" name = "pass" ><br/><br />
                    <div class="row">
                          <input type="submit" value="Login">
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </form>



                   <?php session_start();?>
                            <?php if (isset($_SESSION['errors'])): ?>
                                <?php foreach($_SESSION['errors'] as $error): ?>
                                  <br>
                                  <span class="error"><font color='red'><?php echo $error; ?></font></span>

                                 <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php unset($_SESSION['errors']); ?>
                </div>

            </div>

         </div>

      </div>


    </div>

          </div>


    <div class="push"></div>
</div>


<div class="footer">
  <p>Copyright &copy bsaownersclub.co.uk Rob Jones</p>
</div>


   </body>
</html>
```